# Transforming a pandas dataframe into ndarray numpy

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, group-by, numpy-ndarray

I have a data frame in the following format and want to convert it into a rating matrix. The desired rating matrix would have rows as numbers of users in the data and numbers of items would define the columns of the rating matrix. The rest of the attributes would go as the third dimension in the matrix.

| uid | iid | rating | Attribute1 | Attribute 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | xyz | xyz |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | xyz | xyz |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | xyz | xyz |
| 3 | 3 | 5 | xyz | xyz |

After the transformation, the matrix would look like something the following shape:

(#of users, #of items, #of attributes) => (3,4,2) and axes would be like this:

|/___

However, the values of the matrix should be something like this: 
~|1|2|3|4 
1|?|5|?|5 
2|5|?|?|? 
3|?|?|5|?

For each value of rating, the attribute 1 and attribute 2 would go along the third dimension, as there are only two attributes so the total columns required on third dimension would be 2.

I am trying to accomplish it with numpy,

```
df.values() and reshaping
```

it don't help as this data requires transformation for missing ratings for set of products that users didn't rate. Is there any way to accomplish it with numpy?

I tried to do with numpy but have no clue where to start from.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.